# Magento 2. Sales -> Invoices - add custom column to grid (Override invoice grid collections)

Tags: magento2, sales-invoice

I have added one column in my sales invoice grid. My custom column is in sales_invoice table.

How can I override existing sales invoice grid and add my custom joint query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Add column to sales_order_grid/sales_invoice_grid database table

```
app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Setup/InstallSchema.php
```

Adding following code snippet will do trick for you.

```
$setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable('sales_invoice'),
        'custom_column',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 255,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'Custom Column'
        ]
    );
$setup->getConnection()->addColumn( 
       $setup->getTable('sales_invoice_grid'), 
       'custom_column', 
       [
           'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT, 
           'length' => 255, 
           'nullable' => true, 
           'comment' => 'Custom Column' 
       ]
   );
```

Step 2. Map column using DI configuration to populate it in `sales_invoice_grid` table

The following xml snippet should be added to di configuration inside config node.

```
<config ...>
    ...
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_column" xsi:type="string">
                     sales_invoice.custom_column
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    ...
</config>
```

Step 3. Configure UI grid component to display custom column

```
app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_invoice_grid.xml 
file.
```

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_invoice_columns">
    <column name="custom_column">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

if you want to change collection than override this file in your module with below file.

https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Invoice/Collection.php

Comment: When you filter data it's not working

Comment: can you please check with this - https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Add-tax-amount-to-Orders-Invoice-grid/td-p/76160

Comment: This is the only truly Magento compliant answer

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this:

**Step 1:**

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_invoice_grid.xml**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_invoice_columns">
        <column name="custom_column_name">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Column name</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Step 2:**

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <plugin name="sales_invoice_additional_columns" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\SalesInvoiceGridCollection" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step 3:**

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/SalesInvoiceGridCollection.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection as SalesOrderInvoiceGridCollection;

class SalesInvoiceGridCollection
{
    const SALES_ORDER_INVOICE_GRID_DATA_SOURCE = 'sales_order_invoice_grid_data_source';

    private $collection;

    public function __construct(SalesOrderInvoiceGridCollection $collection)
    {
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public function aroundGetReport(CollectionFactory $subject, \Closure $proceed, $requestName)
    {
        $result = $proceed($requestName);

        if (self::SALES_ORDER_INVOICE_GRID_DATA_SOURCE == $requestName) {
            if ($result instanceof $this->collection) {
                $select = $this->collection->getSelect();
                $select->joinLeft(
                    ['invoice' => $this->collection->getTable('sales_invoice')],
                    'main_table.entity_id = invoice.entity_id',
                    ['custom_column_name']
                );

                return $this->collection;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the answer, Try below solution.

> **Step 1 :** app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_invoice_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_invoice_columns">
        <column name="your_custom_column">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> **Step 2 :** app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <plugin name="sales_invoice_additional_columns" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\SalesInvoiceCustomColumn" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> **Step 3 :** app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/SalesInvoiceCustomColumn.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as SalesOrderGridCollection;

class SalesInvoiceCustomColumn
{
    private $messageManager;
    private $collection;

    public function __construct(
        MessageManager $messageManager,
        SalesOrderGridCollection $collection
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public function aroundGetReport(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $requestName
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($requestName);
        if ($requestName == 'sales_order_invoice_columns') {
            if ($result instanceof $this->collection
            ) {
                $select = $this->collection->getSelect();
                $select->joinLeft(
                    ["secondTable" => $this->collection->getTable("sales_invoice")],
                    'main_table.entity_id = secondTable.entity_id',
                    array('yopur_custom_column')
                );
                return $this->collection;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you filter from store wise or order id wise it's not working

Comment: I have updated, now all the default operations will work

Comment: When I apply order or store wise filtering then it's not work.

Comment: I can't get you...please provide a steps to reproduce

Comment: I am taking about when you apply filtering after adding custom column. https://prnt.sc/p3ohn4

Comment: In my fresh magento version it is working...you got any error in console or network?

Comment: Please add multiple store and place order with diff store wise after that checked

Comment: Yes...My env has 2 stores and have filtered with both stores give exact result - https://prnt.sc/p3ppmm